# C++ macro in scope of if statement not compiling

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, macros, c-preprocessor

I have some code which is supposed to be a thread-safe python/c++ api. I am using the macros `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` and `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS`, which expand to create save thread state and create a lock. I am releasing the lock just before method exit; once inside of `if` statement scope, and once at method scope.

Why does this not compile? It generates the error: `error: _save was not declared in this scope` at the second `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` macro.

```
uint8_t SerialBuffer::push_msg() {

#if defined (UBUNTU)
  Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
#endif

  if (_type == ARRAY) {
      // array access
  } else if (_type == PRIORITY_QUEUE) {
      // queue access
  } else {

    // Placing the return statement in the preprocessor directive
    // has no effect.
#if defined (UBUNTU)
    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
#endif

    return FAIL;
  }

#if defined (UBUNTU)
  Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
#endif

  return SUCCESS;
}
```

I have also tried putting the `return` statement inside of the `#if` directive scope, and this generates the same error. However, this works:

```
uint8_t SerialBuffer::push_msg() {

#if defined (UBUNTU)
  Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
#endif

  if (_type == ARRAY) {
      // array access
  } else if (_type == PRIORITY_QUEUE) {
      // queue access
  } else {
    // NOTE lack of #if directive here.
    // Even though if this code executes the code below will not.
    // Seems like a relatively simple problem for lambda calculus, no?
    return FAIL;
  }

#if defined (UBUNTU)
  Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
#endif

  return SUCCESS;
}
```

Edit: I'm aware that the second example does not do thread clean-up; however, it compiles.

Edit2:
`Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` expands to `{ PyThreadState *_save; _save = PyEval_SaveThread();`

`Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` expands to `PyEval_RestoreThread(_save); }`
NOTE the scoping braces prepending `BEGIN` and appending `END`. Why is it the logical choice for the macro expansion to include scoping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [[Python.Docs]: Initialization, Finalization, and Threads - Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS) (**emphasis** is mine):

> This macro expands to `{ PyThreadState *_save; _save = PyEval_SaveThread();`. Note that it contains an opening brace; **it must be matched** with a following [Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS) macro. See above for further discussion of this macro.

So, the answer to the compile error is pretty clear:

- After preprocessing, the 2<sup>nd</sup> *Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS* produces invalid code (and the enclosing in `#if defined (UBUNTU)` is irrelevant, as it will never work when *UBUNTU* is defined, and it will always work when it isn't):

  - Referencing (inexistent) "*_save*"
  - An extra closing brace ("*}*")

The common usecase for the 2 macros is also exemplified int he above page:

> ```c
> PyThreadState *_save;
> _save = PyEval_SaveThread();
>
> ... Do some blocking I/O operation ...
>
> PyEval_RestoreThread(_save);
> ```

**Why it was designed this way (to include scoping)**? Probably to fail when used **like you did**, because that can cause hard to find errors (your example is pretty simple, but in a more complex piece code with many branches requiring just as many *Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS*, imagine what would mean to miss one, or to call it twice).

In order to fix your problem, you must redesign your code to either:

- Not directly return on failure, but flag it, return (in one place) at the end, and place the *Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS*, just before returning
- Call the macro pair inside each (or where required) of the *if* branches (*ARRAY*, *PRIORITY_QUEUE*, ...)
- Use (the dreaded) *goto*

Answer (score 4):

The preprocessor expands the macro, `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS`, into code that creates a local object named `_save`.

The preprocessor expands the macro, `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS`, into code that uses `_save` to do thread clean-up tasks.

If you put `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` inside the else block, the code created by `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` can't see the local `_save` object, so you get an error message.

On a related topic, I recommend putting `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` and `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` where if the first one executes, then so does the second one. Your second version of the function will not do the thread clean-up tasks for `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` if you have an array type or a priority-queue type.

Try this:

```
uint8_t SerialBuffer::push_msg() {

#if defined (UBUNTU)
  Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
#endif
  uint8_t response = FAIL;

  if (_type == ARRAY) {
      // array access
      response = SUCCESS;
  } else if (_type == PRIORITY_QUEUE) {
      // queue access
      response = SUCCESS;
  }

#if defined (UBUNTU)
  Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
#endif

  return response;
}
```

In this version, the default response is FAIL, so you don't even need the final else section. The other if statements only set the response to SUCCESS if all goes well.

Comment: Do you mean a directive? `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` isn't in an if statement. I should think an `#if` directive is valid, as the preprocessor will see the same macro definition in all valid cases.

Comment: @errolflynn Thanks. I corrected the answer to say "the else block" instead of "an if statement".

Comment: Your style is good. However, there are other cases where I should like to return early to prevent excessive code from running. Do you know why my example doesn't work?

Comment: `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` isn't in the `else` block. It is in the method scope. The variable `_save` should be visible through the entire method.

Comment: @errolflynn Oof! I clearly misread the original code snippet! I have an idea. Send the preprocessed source code to a a file and then check the file for what the preprocessor puts inside that function. You can do that with this command line. `g++ -E file.cpp > file.pp`

Comment: Great tip! See edits. With a `cmake` project, you can run `make file.i` in the binary directory containing the object file target to get the preprocessed file.